# Sci Fi novel narrated from the Alien antagonist's POV

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

Since I read this more than a decade ago my recollection may not be entirely accurate but here goes:

Novel is English, I read this between 2001 and 2005 but it could have been published many years earlier. From what I remember of the writing, the intended audience are most likely young adults but I could be wrong here.

The story is narrated from the antagonist's point of view. The antagonist is an Alien on trial for having committed (or plotting to commit) some sort of crimes against humans. I think genocide was the goal but I could be wrong.

The Alien is somehow able to hear and see what the protagonist does. I believe the protagonist turns the tables by using this to his advantage.

There is a chapter where there is mention of a mind-control helmet. When this helmet is worn by a person the alien is able to control them (or completely brain-wash) them.

The last (or climactic) chapter has some sort of a race against time (or a chase sequence) that involves a tank and the United Nations.

Its definitely not:

- **Illegal Alien** by Robert J. Sawyer
- **Star Maker** by Olaf Stapledon
- **A Fire Upon The Deep** by Vernor Vinge
- **Consider Phlebas** by Iain M. Banks
- **SOLARIS** by Stanislaw Lem
- **Space Odyssey** series by Arthur C. Clarke

Comment: This sounds a lot like volume two of the Voyager series by Ben Bova but that series is definitely not for kids, he did certainly write a lot of young adult stuff so perhaps you have a couple of volumes confused? Specifically take a look at Voyagers II The Alien Within by Ben Bova.

Comment: I'll bet this is _[World of Ptavvs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_of_Ptavvs)_ by Larry Niven. Part of the novel is told from the viewpoint of Kzanol, one of the Thrintun ("Slavers") who had been caught in a stasis field for a billion years. The UN is essentially a world government of Earth. The mind-control helmet is essentially the story's McGuffin. You might have conflated this with something else, because I don't recall a trial; Kzanol is essentially a fugitive the whole novel.